# :hi TabLine ctermfg=Whatever not working on Windows

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

I'm on windows, using vim `8.0`.

When I do

`:hi TabLine ctermfg=Red ctermbg=Black`

The background of the unselected tabs changes, but not the foreground. It stays `Cyan`. It works properly for `TabLineSel` though, but not for this one.

I've quickly looked on Google, but didn't find anything relevant.

Is there a solution (I would like to get the foreground to be `White`)

Even with the option `vim -u NONE`, the default fg color for inactive tabs is Cyan.

[image: Demo]

Comment: Works for me with 8.0. Try starting vim with `-u NONE` to rule out the possibility of a plugin interfering. If I have Airline plugin enabled, for instance,  some highlight settings can't be changed.

Comment: Na, I'm still getting this problem...

Comment: Try adding `cterm=NONE`

Comment: That's the solution!! Thanks! It made it work!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, thanks to @tivn, I got the solution and kind of "understood" the problem.

My guess is that by default, there was something like this:

```
highlight TabLine cterm=underline
```

or

```
highlight TabLine cterm=undercurl
```

Since my terminal (cmder and hyper) did not support underlining, the way they understood it was to set the color to `Cyan`. I tried every other possible value mentioned in the help (`:help attr-list`), and the other result were that the text disappeared (I guess it was the same color as the background).

So, the solution is, as @tivn said, to add `cterm=None`, like this:

```
highlight TabLine cterm=None ctermfg=YourForeground ctermbg=YourBackground
```

And it works!